# Swift 4 map an array to a dictionary by foreign key

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, mapping

I have an object array (foreign key being classId):

```
let studentArray = [Student(id:3, name:"John", classId:1), Student(id:4, name:"Jane", classId:1), Student(id:5, name:"Bill", classId:2)]
```

I am trying to map it to a dictionary with key of classId that looks like this:

```
[1:[Student], 2:[Student]]
```

Is there a good way to do this using a dictionary?
My solution was to use a for loop to iterate through the array and add each object to the dictionary, but this seems inefficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift 4 lets you instantiate a dictionary grouped by a key. Here's [more detail](https://swift.org/blog/dictionary-and-set-improvements/) about it. Here's an example:

```
let studentArray = [Student(id:3, name:"John", classId:1), Student(id:4, name:"Jane", classId:1), Student(id:5, name:"Bill", classId:2)]


let dictByKeyVersionOne = Dictionary(grouping: studentArray, by: {student in student.classId})
```

Alternatively, you can create the dictionary with `$0.classId`, like so:

```
let dictByKeyVersionTwo = Dictionary(grouping: studentArray, by: {$0.classId})
```

Comment: @LeoDabus I like that, too, but I suspect he's somewhat new so I did something that's a little more readable. :)

Comment: @Adrian forgot to mention `Dictionary(grouping: studentArray) {$0.classId}`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you.